# Unsure from Documentation on how to access what stages of the query and where to cache the results?

Tags: frontend, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

[network tab from server [redux dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Mxx.png)Okay, so I am making a little information card of Liverpool FC, using a public API from the back-end. I am now trying to pass my routes through RTK query. I have been trying to mess with with selectResult and I guess there's just something that I am not understanding. It went the states went from Loading... to updating, forcing a re-render & clearing the UI. So, I was trying to get away from the re-render so I passed through my api slice with tag types and `onQueryFulfilled async func`. Idk I've been throwing stuff at the wall to see what sticks. I'm sure its a simple fix, but its gotta be something im missing  or I am not seeing. My idea was that the json element was trying to resolve as a circular dep, so I flatted it and sent it with JSON. But now its returning as JSON on my server, but I can't get that data to stick and stay.

```js
api slice
educerPath:"footyAPI",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'serverorigin',
    mode: 'cors',
credentials:'same-origin',
prepareHeaders:(headers) =>{
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if(accessToken){
        headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
    }   
    return headers;
} }),
tagTypes:['LFCStats', 'LFCInformation', 'LFCFixuturesById', 'LFCPlayersStats'],

    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getLFCStats: builder.query<APIProps, string>({
            query: () =>  '/api/LFCStats',
            providesTags: ['LFCStats'],  
            async onQueryStarted(_, { queryFulfilled }) {
                    // `onStart` side-effect
                    // anything you want to run when the query starts
    
                    try {
                        const response = await queryFulfilled;
                        console.log(response.data); 

                        } catch (err) {
                           console.log(err);
                        // Usage:
                        }
                },
            }),
            getLFCInformation: builder.query({
                query: () => '/api/LFCInformation',
                providesTags: ['LFCInformation'],
                
            }),
            getLFCFixuturesById: builder.query({ 
                query: (id) => `/api/LFCFixuturesById/${id}`,
                providesTags: ['LFCFixuturesById'],
      }),
      getLFCPlayersStats: builder.query({
        query: () => '/api/LFCPlayersStats',
        providesTags: ['LFCPlayersStats'],
          }),
          
       }),
});


test component 

const CardOneLFCTeamStats:React.FC<AppProps>= ():JSX.Element => {
    
    const { data = [], error, isLoading } = useGetLFCStatsQuery('', {
        selectFromResult: ({ data, isLoading, error }) => ({
            data: data,
            isLoading: isLoading,
            error: error,
        }),
        refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
    });

   
    return (

<div className="card-title">
   
    
    {error ? (
        <>
            oh no theres an error
        </>
    ) : isLoading ? (
        <>
            loading...
        </>
    ) : (data) ? (
        <>
            
                { data.map((team: APIProps) => (
                    <div className="card" key={team.team_id}>
                        <h2>{team.name}</h2>
                        <img src={team.logo} alt="team logo" />
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                        <p>Founded: {team.founded}</p>
                        <p>Venue: {team.venue_name}</p>
                        <p>Address: {team.venue}</p>
                        <p>Capacity: {team.capacity}</p>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                ))}
            
        </>
    ) : null}

                       

</div>

    );

};
export default CardOneLFCTeamStats;
```

Yeah, so if anyone has any explicit examples on how I can get this out of the loading state

maybe its how I am trying to access the api? leading undefined?

Object { data: {…}, data1: {…}, data2: {…}, data3: {…} }
​
data: Object { get: "teams/seasons", parameters: {…}, results: 14, … }
​
data1: Object { get: "teams", parameters: {…}, results: 1, … }
​​
errors: Array []
​​
get: "teams"
​​
paging: Object { current: 1, total: 1 }
​​
parameters: Object { id: "40" }
​​
response: Array [ {…} ]
​​
results: 1
​​
: Object { … }
​
data2: Object { get: "fixtures/headtohead", parameters: {…}, results: 39, … }
​
data3: Object { get:

Comment: What exact rerender do you want to avoid here? It seems you need both a rerender at the loading state and when data arrives, otherwise your UI would be wrong?
Either way, please don't copy data into another slice, and the rerender comes from the hook, so you don't have any need to do additional things in `onQueryStarted` here - that is outside the React render cycle.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Well when I am in dev tools, i see execute query fulfilled and then it subscribes looking for updates which is expected am i right. I guess im trying to figure out why it subscribes and it appears that i cant access the data? Its there somewhere right?

Comment: It subscribes so it knows that while your component is mounted, that data shouldn't be cache-collected. The data should be available in your component through the `data` property that you get back from the hook.

Comment: Ok, so I was right in thinking that. So if the data isnt available is it a mounting issue? Or am I not retrieving it right from my server?

Comment: Looking at the devtools, do you see a fulfilled action? Looking at the network tab, is the request finishing?

Comment: If the "data" isn't available it means it hasn't been cached yet. The endpoint is still loading/fetching it. `data` is the latest returned result, if present. What is the actual issue or problem you are having in your code that you want resolved?

Comment: Well it will fulfill and the data is held in query resolves but then I get an empty object… but i was only looking at the fulfilled action and the updated subscription. I foolishly didnt look at the network tab. But why would I receive an empty object as the latest returned result? Screenshot coming next comment

Comment: Could be CORS blocking your access to the data. In that case, the server would tell the browser that the request result is not allowed to be read by JavaScript and you'd have to configure your server accordingly. You'd see that in the Devtools.

Comment: okay so i figured out the cors issues.. but it seems when the component unmounts my app crashes and in redux dev tools I see         name(pin): "AbortError"
        message(pin): "Aborted"

Comment: Also i think I might be dumb, because the app is crashing because I am trying to call multiple endpoints to all show up in four different cards, so for that I am going to need to customize the query with a func correct? @phry

Comment: All that sounds very weird... could you maybe follow the official tutorial to make sure you're not doing something very weird here? Your app should never crash... https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics

Comment: Maybe not crash… but when the component unmounts the data doesnt have a chance to resolve…if this was fetch i would throw this in a use effect but i know i cant throw a query hook there… but i guess i dont understand how skip token comes into play. But i expect, that if i use one query between three components i should be able to see all data from the endpoint concurrently.